AWS Bedrock agent error as "Your request rate is too high. Reduce the frequency of requests."
I created bedrock agent with action group. When i am testing the agent, it is showing error as "Your request rate is too high. Reduce the frequency of requests."
I am using claude 3.5 sonnet.
Any solutions will be helpful.

Hi there,
I'm Dennis, a Developer Advocate at AWS. I'm really sorry about the trouble this caused and want to thank you for highlighting the issue. We're aware of the problem and are actively working on a resolution.
I'd like to help you directly with this matter. For privacy reasons, it would be best if you could reach out to me via my official Amazon email at traubd@amazon.com or a DM on LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/dennis-traub/
I can then gather more details and personally look into your case.
Thanks again, your feedback helps us fix things faster and better!

It's likely that the model that you are using for the Action Group is not enabled in your AWS Account.
Proceed to go to "Amazon Bedrock" service. Then click on "Model Access", and request access to the corresponding model (example: "Claude 3.5 Sonnet").

If this does not solve it, it might be an "AWS Quota" applied at that model invoke limit.
Go to "Service Quotas", then search "Invoke", and make sure that you have enough applied account quota values for that specific model.

This should be enough, as the error is a missleading one.
